# Python post requests

Tags: python, request

This code returns a 500 status code. when I replace type with "groupLink" it works for the group link, but when I try abbreviation it doesn't

```
import requests

headers = {
    "Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "User-Agent": "Firefox",
    "Host": "#.com",
    "Content-Length":"39"
}

payload = {
    "xml":"1",
    "type":"abbreviation",
    "value":"stackover"
}



r = requests.post("http://#.com/actions/AvailabilityCheck/", headers=headers, data=payload)
print(r)
```

Comment: I don't quite get what the problem is, please try to clarify it, maybe post the code that is not working.

Comment: What is the error message from the response?

Comment: Well, it should return if the abbreviation of my value is taken or not, but instead I get 500

Comment: @nooby: Where is this API documented?

Comment: @Blender no API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your session in cookie.

```
import requests

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'text/plain;charset=UTF-8',
    'Cookie': 'sessionid=6a3a05dsd29709707c27991f; steamCountry=KR%7C01d0fa93544aeb0f7d0de4fc244d8b25',
}

payload = {
    "xml":"1",
    "type":"abbreviation",
    "value":"stackover"
}

r = requests.post("http://steamcommunity.com/actions/AvailabilityCheck/", headers=headers, data=payload)
print(r.text)
```

This code prints `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><response><results><![CDATA[Missing Data]]></results></response>`

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
import requests
import json
headers = {
    "Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "User-Agent": "Firefox",
    "Host": "steamcommunity.com",
    "Content-Length":"39"
}
payload = {
    "xml":"1",
    "type":"groupLink",
    "value":"stackover"
}
r =    requests.post("http://steamcommunity.com/actions/AvailabilityCheck/",  headers=headers, data=json.dumps(payload))
print(r)
```

Comment: Just tried, and I put print(r.text), and I get.. "<![CDATA[Missing Data]]></results></response>"

Comment: Also, I can get it too work for the groupLink, but not the abbreviation

Comment: I dont know what data is to be sent in the "value". What I know is he was sending a dictionary, instead he should have used json.dumps because of which he was getting 500 as the application was not able to get the required data.

Comment: @SandeepHukku: requests URL-encodes `data` when it's a dictionary. Sending it as JSON won't work if the server isn't expecting JSON.